# Configuring Linux server for long term use (no remote access granted after deployment)

Tags: linux, debian, configuration, cron

Not sure if the title is the best but to explain a bit more: I have to deploy a Linux box on a customer network that I will not have remote or regular access to.  I want to ensure that the system functions for a long time without any problem.  My biggest concern is to run out of disk space.  It can quickly be eaten up by various logs and that will have a cascading effect on everything else.  I'm going to setup some cron jobs that clear various logs every X hours but I need to make sure I'm covering all my bases.

What configuration changes/best practices should I make before deploying and what should I focus my maintenance cron jobs on?  In case it matters, I'm running Debian 9.

Comment: Make it easy for a local support person to increase log verbosity when troubleshooting is required and log little when not needed. Consider configuring your application to log to [journald](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html), [rsyslog](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/log_rotation_fix_size.html) and such which natively support log rotation / deletion / retention based on file size and won't depend on age or external scripts to do that.

Comment: I guess you are using "standard" distros which have log rotation enabled by default. If you are concerned about disk space, make a cron which will check disk free space and email you once it is out of space. Then your client should allow access, and you will then know what to fix, after that you are free. (Answer is as detailed as the question is)

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to install cron and logrotate and configure logrotate to rotate logs periodically or after they grow to a certain size. Then check your services they are writting everything to log-files. If something is sent to stdout/stderr then install rsyslog and use logger(1) everywhere in your scripts to redirect everything to syslog.
Additionally check your cron settings to not send anything to mail, as mailqueue can eat space too. Redirecting all cron tasks' output (stderr&stdout) to logger(1) effectively prevents any emails from crond while allowing you to examine execution output of the tasks.

Example line in /etc/cron.d/ping-localhost:

```
*/29 * * * * root /usr/bin/ping -c 3 localhost  2>&1 | logger -t ping-localhost
```

And sample of output:

```
me@host:~$~> tail -8 /var/log/messages
Nov 20 12:59:34 host ping-localhost: PING host.local (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
Nov 20 12:59:34 host ping-localhost: 64 bytes from host.local (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.034 ms
Nov 20 12:59:35 host ping-localhost: 64 bytes from host.local (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms
Nov 20 12:59:36 host ping-localhost: 64 bytes from host.local (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
Nov 20 12:59:36 host ping-localhost: 
Nov 20 12:59:36 host ping-localhost: --- host.local ping statistics ---
Nov 20 12:59:36 host ping-localhost: 3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms 
Nov 20 12:59:36 host ping-localhost: rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.034/0.043/0.053/0.010 ms
```

Comment: How do you check and set cron settings for redirecting output?

Comment: I've updated my answer with example.